# Undo cell deletion in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to use a shortcut to undo cell deletion in Google Colab. When I delete a cell, Google Colab displays a hint that I can undo the action by using **Ctrl + M Z**

Is this shortcut means clicking **Ctrl + M + Z** all at the same time? Because it is not working for me.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62522472/gettinng-back-cells-after-being-deleted-in-colab) - the advice is to use `revision history`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "first press `Ctrl+M`, **release**, then press `Z`" - surely this is a bit confusing!

Answer (score 1):

you can restore a deleted cell (by pressing the escape key) and then pressing "z" it works for google colab and kaggle notebooks. [kaggle questions](https://www.kaggle.com/code/winternguyen/modeling-energy-efficiency-residential-building/comments)